# Trying to use Docker for the first time: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (2d9

Tags: postgresql, docker, web-applications, webserver

I am trying to build a Flask/PostgreSQL/SQLAlchemy/Alembic/libpq-dev/psycopg2 web app on macOS. 
I have never used Docker so I thought I'd give it a try. I installed it and was going through the Get Started steps.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f

$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.15.0, build b48dc28d
```

Then I went to step two:

```
$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/
```

Everything was working just like the documentation, but then I tried the next step, "starting a dockerized web server," and this is what happened...

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
159841d356d8cf6b16fd592b22daa76f3a734a8b35bf24f9f83b3dce6486d49e
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (2d93210e398bf70794b706d6e07ca2c2b78297b9f337271710f4c62be8a79b7d): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

So, I googled the error and have found numerous instances of this or similar errors on forums like github and stackoverflow. I tried all of the steps to resolve it that I could find.

```
sudo netstat -nl -p tcp  | grep 8123
Password:

MyMacName@My-MacBook-Pro ~
$ sudo netstat -nl -p tcp  | head
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49655        54.174.175.30.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49654        192.30.253.117.443     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49653        50.16.137.101.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49652        192.30.253.125.443     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49651        151.101.4.133.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49650        151.101.4.133.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49649        151.101.56.133.443     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.94.49648        34.238.78.202.443      ESTABLISHED
```

but I don't know what to make of any of this so it doesn't do me any good on it's own. So I found these steps and tried them...

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
2eb7a75a5fd7

$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q);
2eb7a75a5fd7

$ docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
"docker volume rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker volume rm --help'.

Usage:  docker volume rm [OPTIONS] VOLUME [VOLUME...]

Remove one or more volumes

$ docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)
Error response from daemon: bridge is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
Error response from daemon: host is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
Error response from daemon: none is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed

$ sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN
Password:

httpd        97               root    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
mysqld      113             _mysql   19u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8a1dd         0t0        TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld      113             _mysql   22u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8a79d         0t0        TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
awacsd      215               root    8u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8b31d         0t0        TCP [fd24:e01e:118f:e97:75e1:c8cf:5efb:c34c]:4488 (LISTEN)
httpd       234     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd       235     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd       236     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd       237     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd       238     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
rapportd    402     MyMacName    3u     IPv4 0xb250f70d1db86225         0t0        TCP *:58588 (LISTEN)
rapportd    402     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8851d         0t0        TCP *:58588 (LISTEN)
postgres    441     MyMacName    5u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8965d         0t0        TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres    441     MyMacName    6u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8ad5d         0t0        TCP [fe80:1::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres    441     MyMacName    7u     IPv4 0xb250f70d0cf3db85         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
Adobe\x20   567     MyMacName   13u     IPv4 0xb250f70d1335fe45         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:15292 (LISTEN)
Adobe\x20   567     MyMacName  31u     IPv4 0xb250f70d0ecd1225         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:15393 (LISTEN)
httpd       744     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
node        746     MyMacName   15u     IPv4 0xb250f70d0e5be225         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:49255 (LISTEN)
httpd       748     MyMacName    4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd       749     MyMacName   4u     IPv6 0xb250f70d0ca8909d         0t0        TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
cupsd      3415               root    5u     IPv6 0xb250f70d13944e9d         0t0        TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      3415               root    6u     IPv4 0xb250f70d16c228c5         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
pgAdmin4   4253     MyMacName  14u     IPv4 0xb250f70d0e7638c5         0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:54792 (LISTEN)
```

Unfortunately, I do not know what any of this means either. I thought the problem may have been that the last line shows PostgreSQL's PgAdmin4 is running. So went into Utility Monitor and Force Quit that. There were still 5-6 instances of 'postgres' that I could not get to force quit for some reason. It must be something to do with my Mac coming with postgres of some kind.

Does anything I've pasted here help someone who knows Docker diagnose what I can do to move past this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508018/docker-driver-failed-programming-external-connectivity-on-endpoint-webserver)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
159841d356d8cf6b16fd592b22daa76f3a734a8b35bf24f9f83b3dce6486d49e
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (2d93210e398bf70794b706d6e07ca2c2b78297b9f337271710f4c62be8a79b7d): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

You can docker -d -p [another_host_port]:80 -- name webserver nginx to bind it into another port instead of 80, I think there is another app or instance using port 80 that you haven't find.

Docker port binding syntax: `host:guest`. 
(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Here nginx run in a Docker instance and expose 80 itself, so we map nginx's 80 (guest) to our desired port (host) and we access the app by that port.

Comment: Ahh... okay. I think I understand. So... I ran this...

`$ docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
46af690fbd45
159841d356d8


$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
46af690fbd45
159841d356d8


$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
[... It listed 10-12 Deleted images ...]


$ docker run -d -p 180:80 --name webserver nginx
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.`

Comment: Please try relogin via `docker login` by your Docker Hub's username. I've tested on Linux with your `docker run -d -p 180:80 --name webserver nginx` and everything is okay.
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2640

Or you could `docker pull nginx` before `docker run` to make sure your docker engine can pull the base nginx image before it can run.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, but docker restart doesn't help.
So I started Kitematic and opened the settings of my postgres container and changed the configured port to **localhost:5432** again. Now it works for me.

Or use these commands:

```
docker stop postgres
docker commit postgres postgres2
docker run -p 54320:5432 -td postgres2
```